# Find local python package registry and remove

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools

I'm following the Django example to create my own reusable app. I created it following the Tutorials: [Advanced tutorial: How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/reusable-apps/)

After installing it with pip, I found some error so I removed the directory manually rather than using pip uninstall. When I made some change and wanted to re-install I got an error:

```
(venv) C:\source_code\django_test>pip install --user django-polls/dist/django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Processing c:\source_code\django_test\django-polls\dist\django-polls-0.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: django-polls
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for django-polls ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\d0\f6\b0\5993fd9396ff005d6d1f1af971ea04814e5f6b9efcc8f9ea89
Successfully built django-polls
Installing collected packages: django-polls
  Found existing installation: django-polls 0.1
    Not uninstalling django-polls at c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages, outside environment c:\source_code\django_test\venv
    Can't uninstall 'django-polls'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed django-polls-0.1

(venv) C:\source_code\django_test>
```

Despite it shows "Successfully installed", there is no new directory created under my Django project. It seems that despite I removed the directory, Python recorded the installation somewhere (like registry) and detected the version conflict.

I wonder where does Python store such information and how can I clean up the registry item so I can install it again just like I have never installed it before?

By the way, I cannot uninstall it with pip either:

```
(venv) C:\source_code\django_test>pip uninstall django-polls
Not uninstalling django-polls at c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages, outside environment c:\source_code\django_test\venv
Can't uninstall 'django-polls'. No files were found to uninstall.
```

Comment: Not uninstalling django-polls at **c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages**

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue. If you installed package with `--user`, it is located under your user's home folder. Just clean up everything related to your package's name in `~/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages`